# I want to stop execution of the @Test method if @BeforeMethod is failed. How to achieve This

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I go with a general example. I have login code in the `@Before` method:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setUp(){
  ///somelogin logic
}

@Test
public void Testdashboard() throws Exception{
  //Some Dashboard validation logic
}
```

So here if login fails in the `@BeforeMethod` I want to stop the execution of `@Test` method how to do this?

Comment: You can use dependsOnMethods attribute for like: @Test(dependsOnMethods={"setUp"})
    public void Testdashboard() {
    }

Comment: @Anand I don't think the test method will run if beforemethod fails. It should get skipped automatically.

Comment: Pls accept any of the below answers that you feel appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the test method will run if beforemethod fails. The  @test method should get skipped automatically.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use `dependsOnMethods` attribute in `@Test` annotation as below:</s>

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"setUp"})
public void Testdashboard() {
//Some Dashboard validation logic
}
```

I guess it would not be possible as method annotated with `@BeforeMethod` is not a test method. It is used to perform any setup prior to execution of test method.

If you want test method to depend on other method then you need to use `dependsOnMethods` attribute whose value is some other method annotated with `@Test`.

You can do this by using below option:

-`configfailurepolicy`-  Its value can be `skip|continue`.
This determines whether TestNG should continue to execute the remaining tests in the suite or skip them if an @Before* method fails. Default behaviour is skip.

Refer to link:
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: i tried this but getting below error

org.testng.TestNGException: 
com.DashboardValidation.Testdashboard() is depending on method public void com.DashboardValidation.setUp() throws java.lang.Exception, which is not annotated with @Test or not included.